# Openam policy decision with (session and ldap filter) environment condition

Tags: policy, openam

I think I am doing something stupid and can't find documentation around it.

[image]

I have this above policy set in openAM and trying to validate it with `json/policies?_action=evaluate`. But I can't find how would I have to pass the environment key and values for the above-configured condition? I have tried them in a cookie or in headers but don't seem to get it right. should I add them in the environment and then write the script to handle (and return authorize true) that from the request in the openAM services? OR do I have to add custom service in for identity and that would handle this? OR am I missing this completely?

request for validate is:

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://0.0.0.0:8080/openam/json/policies?_action=evaluate' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-API-Version: resource=1.0' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Cookie: iPlanetDirectoryPro=<token-of-web-agent>' \
  -H 'Host: 0.0.0.0:8080' \
  -d '{
    "resources":["/members"],
    "application":"iPlanetAMWebAgentService",
    "subject":{
        "ssoToken":"<ssoToken-of-demo-user>"
    },
  "environment": {}
}'
```

Comment: Please always provide the OpenAM version and fork. Be aware that there is only ForgeRock OpenAM up to version 13.5.0. Never version of ForgeRock is not called OpenAM, but ForgeRock Access Manangement. This matters a lot!

Comment: I am using forgerock AM 6.0 - this is docker image I am using - `docker pull gcr.io/forgerock-io/openam:6.0.0`

Comment: The session property and ldap filter conditions don't really depend on the environment map being populated, so I'm not sure it will make a difference if it is defined.